# Por que o ponto é substituído por vírgula ao enviar o Sqlcommand do c# ao banco de dados?

Tags: c#

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que na primeira imagem o valor ainda está correto: 150.45
O problema é que quando envio o comando ao banco de dados o ponto é substituido por virgula, na segunda imagem eu capturei o comando pelo SQL Server Profiler e podemos notar que o ponto realmente foi substituido por virgula. Como posso resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Acabei descobrindo como resolver o problema, vou compartilhar aqui talvez ajude outra pessoa.

```
var cmdText = ($@"INSERT INTO PESSOASERVICOPRESTADO (CODPESSOA, DESCRICAOSERVICO, 
VALORTOTAL, VALORPAGO, PAGO, DATASERVICO ) VALUES ({servico.CodPessoa}, 
'{servico.DescricaoServico}', 
{servico.ValorTotal.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}, 
{servico.ValorPago.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}, '{servico.Pago}' 
,'{servico.DataServico}')");
```

Basta adicionar o seguinte código ao comando SQl: 
        ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
dessa forma o Sql server ignora a configuração de região e manda a instrução com o ponto ao invés de trocar por virgula que causaria problema.